# Problem with apps. Going from iPhone to Android

Tags: applications, google-account, ios

I had an iPhone and am switching to Android now.

When I sign into my Gmail, will it show all my iPhone apps on my new Android device?

Comment: No! You need either transferring them using an app on the play store or simply download them.

Answer (score 3):

iOS and Android are different operating systems. As you probably couldn't run Windows applications on your iPhone, you neither can run iOS apps on Android. Alone for this reason they cannot simply "show up" on your Android phone.

Second, the Google account system isn't synchronized with Apple's iTunes (or the iCloud), so Gmail couldn't even know about them. Some might even come pre-installed with your new Android device.

There are means of migrating your data (contacts, calendars, photos, etc.) from your iOS world to "planet Android", see e.g.

- [How do I transfer iPhone contacts to an Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/7358/16575)
- [How do I migrate my SMS (text messages) from iPhone to Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/38960/16575)
- [How can I transfer SMS messages from my old iPhone to my new Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/716/16575)

But for apps, you need to find "new counter-parts":

- Some apps exist in both universes. Check with the developers homepages to see if they have a link to an Android app as well.
- Some apps are rather "exclusive" to either Android or iOS. Here you will have to find the best alternative. A search for `<YourAppName> Android`, using the search engine of your choice, might be a good starter for that. [My Android app listings](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php) can be of assistance as well. If you still didn't find anything, take a look at [Where to ask for app recommendations?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575) and follow the advice there.

Some of your iOS apps might allow to export their data, and their Android counterparts might allow to import them then. But mostly, you will have to start from the scratch.

Have a good start with Android – and in case of trouble or missing information, you already found a good place to ask!